# Values are not updated in input/select tags on server side after clicking submit ASP.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, forms

Using a one pager template for asp.net application, and as ASP supports one form per page so can only use one big form in that page, testing my first panel in the page after entering a value and clicking submit in that panel! the value is null in textbox, and select only return 0 whatever the value is selected.
What can i do? can't i use just one form and to get values from all input fields.

```
<body>
<form id="mainform" class="subscriptionForm" runat="server">
.
.
.
    <asp:Panel ID="timepanel" runat="server" > 
          <label for="intext">Enter Time</label>
                    <select id="hr" runat="server" style="background-color:#fff; display:inline; color:#0f8094; width:10%; border-style:none; opacity:.7;" name="hr">
                            <option>0</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option>
                            <option>7</option><option>8</option><option>9</option><option>10</option><option>11</option><option>12</option></select><%--<asp:TextBox name="name" id="asdas" runat="server" />--%>
       Hr
                    <select id="min" runat="server" style="background-color:#fff; display:inline; color:#0f8094; width:10%; border-style:none; opacity:.7;">
                            <option>0</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option><option>8</option><option>9</option><option>10</option><option>11</option><option>12</option><option>13</option><option>14</option><option>15</option><option>16</option><option>17</option><option>18</option><option>19</option><option>20</option><option>21</option><option>22</option><option>23</option><option>24</option><option>25</option><option>26</option><option>27</option><option>28</option><option>29</option><option>30</option><option>31</option><option>32</option><option>33</option><option>34</option><option>35</option><option>36</option><option>37</option><option>38</option><option>39</option><option>40</option><option>41</option><option>42</option><option>43</option><option>44</option><option>45</option><option>46</option><option>47</option><option>48</option><option>49</option><option>50</option><option>51</option><option>52</option><option>53</option><option>54</option><option>55</option><option>56</option><option>57</option><option>58</option><option>59</option></select> Min                        
                        <%--<label style="display:inline; "><input type="checkbox" id="textalert" style="display:inline;" />Text Alert</label>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" id="soundalert" />Sound Alert</label>--%>



                        <%--<div style="margin-left:150px; margin-top:20px;">--%>
                            <asp:LinkButton  runat="server" ID="send_input"  style="padding:15px; background-color:green;" OnClick="start_timer" Text="Enter" />
                        <%--</div>--%>
      </asp:Panel>
.
.
.
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Please take a moment to look through the [edit help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Formatting on SO is a little different than other sites.

Comment: @gunr2171 yeh my bad! just noticed that!